# ArgGis seems to snap but doesn't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, snapping

We are building a project in ArgGis 10.2 were we create buildings using rectangles. Some of them need to be  attached at one or more sides (they have common walls), so we would use snapping to snap vertex to edge to create a new building next to another.  It seems to snap, but when zoomed in (1:0.3 scale) we can see that they are not snapped.  at 1:1 looks good, but if we look even closer we see that the lines or point are not joined.

Comment: I realize that this could be a problem in theory, but what is the intended scale for this project? Are you really going to export anything in 1:0.3? Ín the end, does it even matter?

Comment: Is your data frame in the same coordinate system as both layers you are editing? ArcGIS' on-the-fly projection for layers could cause this discrepancy.

Comment: we do use the same coordinate system throughout the database. it seems like running topology will bring up errors were 2 shapes meet.

Answer (score 1):

when working at such a large scale, you should check that you are not exceeding the precision of storage of your vertices. You would not see any difference when you snap a vertex (where the stored coordinates are already "rounded"), but an edge can have positions which falls between two possible coordinates. If you are going to use this in another software or at a higher precision, then I suggest that you insert a vertex at the position on the edge where you want to snap. Otherwise ArcGIS will behave as if they were exactly the same anyway.

Comment: this is one solution we've thought of using.adding that extra vertex will align the edges perfectly, but because it is a large scale project we want to use as few vertex-es as we possibly can, to reduce the final file size.

Comment: does the thickness of the shape border influence how spanning is made?

Comment: not in theory, the thickness of the symbol only affect graphical display.